# can't click flashplayer dialog

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Sometimes flashplayer's dialog cameras and microphones permit denial can not press.
is this flashplayer's bug or swf size or something else?

OS          : MAC OSX 10.8.2 
firefox     : 18.0.1 
flashplayer : 11,5,31,137

same problem this forum, but flashplayer version is different.
https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-4656

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the case that over the flash security popups is html container. Test it with browser developer tools.